# How to change menu item colors?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I change the color of `PopupMenuItem` in Flutter? I can't find any property of doing it in the `PopupMenuItem`

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to change my theme of `cardColor`

```
ThemeData(
  cardColor: Colors.grey,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom item by extending `PopupMenuItem` and then overriding the `buildChild()` method.

In this method, you can build your child however you like.

```
class MyPopupMenuItem<T> extends PopupMenuItem<T> {
  const MyPopupMenuItem({
    Key key,
    T value,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, value: value, child: child);

  @override
  Widget get child => super.child;

  @override
  _MyPopupMenuItemState<T> createState() => _MyPopupMenuItemState<T>();
}

class _MyPopupMenuItemState<T>
    extends PopupMenuItemState<T, MyPopupMenuItem<T>> {
  @override
  Widget buildChild() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for some simple way. cardColor is pretty easy to get things done.

Answer (score 0):

For Simplicity, what you can do -

```
MatrialApp(
theme: ThemeData(
cardColor: Colors.blue, # set your color
);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any difference between mine and your answer.